# Update item's property in a versioned repository in code

Tags: java, repository, atg, commerce

I'm kinda new in the Oracle Commerce ATG technology and don't understand many of its concepts yet. By now I have encountered an issue I couldn't find any resolution to. 
I'm trying to update a particular property of an item in a versioned repository using the standard way through the method *setPropertyValue()* on a MutableRepositoryItem object and then *updateItem()* on the repository object itself. But it doesn't work and I get that error message.
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBrJg.png)

Maybe someone could enlighten me what should I do to resolve that issue?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are trying to programatically update a repository item in the BCC/CA module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for updating a versioned and a non-versioned repository is different.

**1. Non-Versioned Repository:** 
This is pretty much easy, as you can simply get a repository item, change properties using *setPropertyValue()* method. Update the item and you're done.
For more details, you can refer HERE: http://learnoracleatg.blogspot.in/2015/04/art212-how-to-query-atg-repository-from.html

**2. Versioned Repository:**
The concept of updating a versioned repository is a bit tricky and very much different from a non-versioned repository.
Since Versioned repositories are meant to be updated from BCC, ATG handles pretty much everything itself when using BCC. However, when you are doing things programatically, there are some things which you have to take care:-

- Create a User/Persona
- Create a Project
- Create corresponding process using a workflow
- Use a development line
- Import the assets [Or use repository statements like you did for a non-versioned repository]
- Advance the workflow.